# Reopen PhD career question?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, reopen-request

[How does the process for applying for jobs look for a PhD?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/37053/2322)

I made a fairly meaningful edit to this question, as I feel it is on-topic here as well as  good question.

I think it's a question which is meaningful now and answerable.

Hoping to get some reopen votes or discussion!

Comment: related: [Aggressive Edits](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2153/168)

Comment: There were 3 reopen votes, so adding yours and mine makes 5.  Reopened.